# How to reference the parent object when using prototypes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, function, prototype

I have created an utility function which I include in almost all Javascript code I write. The purpose of the said function is to simply remove one element from an array. It takes an array and an index as the arguments, and returns the array which has the required element removed.

Here's the function:

```
sliceHere = function(array, i)
{
    buffOne = array.slice(0, i);
    buffTwo = array.slice(i + 1);

    return buffOne.concat(buffTwo);         
}
```

It works quite alright. If I had an array `a = ["a", "b", "c"]`, and I wanted to remove the `"a"` from it, I'd simply do `a = sliceHere(a, 0);`.

Although this **did** work, I wanted to replace it with something more "elegant". What I wanted to do is to make the function `sliceHere` a method of **all** the arrays I have. So I could simply do `a.sliceHere(0)` and achieve the same effect. It just feels like a better way of doing things, correct me if I'm wrong.

What I did was this:

```
sliceHere = function(i)
{
    buffOne = this.slice(0, i);
    buffTwo = this.slice(i + 1);

    this = buffOne.concat(buffTwo);         
}

Array.prototype.sliceHere = sliceHere
```

This didn't seem like it would work at all. Because I knew that "this" probably wasn't the actual array. **How do I reference the array from inside of a method?**

Comment: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/09/08/quot-extension-method-quot-in-javascript/

Comment: You could just do [`a.splice(0,1);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)? And you wouldn't have to even assign it to anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) already does the same thing:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var i = 1;
array.splice(i, 1);
array; // [2, 3]
```

Okay, let's re-invent the wheel:

With splice:

```
Array.prototype.sliceHere = function(i) {
    this.splice(i, 1);
};
```

Without splice:

```
Array.prototype.sliceHere = function(i) {
     var i_want_you = this.slice(0, i).concat(this.slice(i + 1));
     this.length = 0;
     this.push.apply(this, i_want_you);  // <-- Modifies all keys, indirectly
};
```

If you do not want the method to show up in `for(.. in ..)` loops, use [`Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'sliceHere', {value: /*function here*/});`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: Sure, but it still might be nice for future readers of the OP's question to know what the actual answer is.

Comment: Oh, that's nice, didn't know that... Thanks I guess, but I'm gonna accept Sergey's answer instead, he **did** answer my question after all.

Comment: @Bane it's your first code snippet copypasted, and that's the real answer? `:'(`

Comment: @Bane Updated my answer. It's a square wheel though.

Comment: I don't think that reinventing the wheel is always negative. Students have to do this all the time to learn. I am a student and I wouldn't know this if I hadn't tried to reinvent the wheel. Also, what exactly does `push.apply` do?

Comment: @Bane [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a method which modifies the array directly, by adding all arguments at the end of the array. [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) invokes a method, sets the context (`"this"`) to the first argument, and passed the all elements of the second argument (array) as arguments to the function. So, `this.push.apply` adds the new array to the current array (which I emptied by setting length to zero).

Answer (score 2):

`this` is always readonly so you cannot assign a new array to it, you should return an updated value instead. Here is an updated version of your example:

```
sliceHere = function(i)
{
    buffOne = this.slice(0, i);
    buffTwo = this.slice(i + 1);

    return buffOne.concat(buffTwo);
}

Array.prototype.sliceHere = sliceHere;

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr = arr.sliceHere(1);
```

Comment: So there is no way to somehow actually **write** into the object? And if so, how does `splice` work, then?

Comment: `splice` modifies the existing instance in place, no replacement of the object happens.

Comment: You can call object methods, change its properties values, but no, you cannot make it point to another object.

Comment: You could: `while (i < tail.length) this[i] = this[++i]; this.length--;` (note that I'm deliberately avoiding to use `splice` in this example, as it would make the whole exercise moot)